# The order of the test methods in a Test Suite by JUnit4Spring

Tags: junit4, testcase, spring-junit

Is the order of the test methods in a Test Suite by JUnit4Spring reliable?

Otherwise, is there anyway to enforce the order?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is great!
If you are using JUnit 4.11, you can also use the @FixMethodOrder annotation
See example:

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly, order by method name, alphabetically